# how to copy excel column data to another worksheet and do text-to-columns programatically

Tags: arrays, vb.net, excel

I have a working copy of an application that will open workbooks/sheets and copy data succesffully between the two then saves but I need to parse some data as I copy it into another cell.

I was thinking..

~ create array
~ get all values in xlSourceFile.worksheets("sheet1") and store into an array
~ parse through the array extracting the data I need (text-to-column programatically)
~ write the array data to two specific columns in excel worksheet

the data I am trying to parse is Firstname / Lastname - Email and I want this as a result:

```
Joe Shmoe to go into one column //  Joe Shmoes Email to another column.
```

I am writing this in vb.net using the imports Microsoft.Office.Interop to manipulate Excel.

Comment: currently developing the solution now, I use this as help/psuedo code to get the ball rolling for myself. Will 'EDIT' when I am further was just looking to see if there are some built in functions that I do not know about as of yet that could be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excuse the formatting, I'm new to SO.  This is VBA but I believe the general logic will work.  It assumes that the email address has no space padding after it.  It searches backward on the raw combined string for the first blank space and flags that as the start of the email address (end of the name).

It loops out when the next cell is empty.

The data is assumed to look like this:
"First Name Last Name myaddress@example.com"

```
For Each cell In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A")
   i = i + 1
   If cell = "" Then GoTo loopout
   rawstring = cell.Value
   'rawString = "First Name Last Name myaddress@example.com"
   emailStartPosition = InStrRev(rawstring, " ")
   myname = Left(rawstring, emailStartPosition)
   myemail = Right(rawstring, Len(rawstring) - emailStartPosition)
   Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i).Value = myname
   Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & i).Value = myemail
Next
loopout:
End Sub
```

Column B will have the name and Column C will have the email address.

Comment: this is much cleaner than my current approach, I am currently getting the data into an array then seperating the data from there based on a delimeter "JOE SHMOE - email@email.com" ( notice the space on each side of the dash, then I was going to load that data into the other worksheet from each sepereate array

Comment: the only issue I am having is the if cell = "" then goto loopout. I undersand what it is doing , breaking out of this loop once it finds an empty cell, the problem is I cannot recreate this behaviour in vb.net .. here is my attempt  If cell = Nothing Then
                    Exit For
                End If

Comment: Yeah I wasn't too happy with that logic.  I know there's a way to figure out how many non-blank cells are in a range (for stopping the loop). Haven't got there yet.

Comment: incase you are looking for the answer ... I dont know how to format on here so goodluck on that part ...For Each cell In xlDataToConvertWorkSheet.Range("R2:R" & xlDataToConvertWorkSheet.Range("R2").End(Excel.XlDirection.xlDown).Row) next